# Get node info inside kubernetes pod/container

Tags: kubernetes

is there a way to get info about node in pod/container like hostname, cpu and ram info or how to mount files/dirs, that has this info(/proc/cpuinfo, /sys/class/dmi/id) ?

I try hostPath, https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/ just get only pod info not node and same with init container

Answer (score 0):

There are no predefined variables like for Pod in K8s.

However, each Kubernetes node, whether from Minikube or an EKS node pool, maintains a file named `/etc/machine-id`. So you can use `cat /etc/machine-id` to get a unique identifier for every Kubernetes node. This identifier aligns perfectly with the machine ID retrieved through `kubectl get nodes -o json | jq -r .items[].status.nodeInfo.machineID`.

This method doesn't require invoking APIs, which is more complicated, making integrating with shell scripts or container environments simpler.